# Vue.js: Vue-Carousel jumping to last item in array on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently working on an application that involves scrolling through members from two different lists. Once you click one you see their image and bio. We added up and down arrows to scroll through their biography, but when i click the down arrow it seems that the active class on the carousel slide now jumps to the last member in my array, but still displays the member i was already on. To add to that I cannot swipe back and forth once i am on a member (this is something that I could do previously.) I know this probably isn't the best description and there is only so much code I can show, as I cannot display the entire application.

I wanted to also note that if I refresh my page, everything works as expected. Does this mean something isn't initializing correctly?

this is the code specific to the page i am talking about:

```html
<template>
  <div class="member-info-carousel">
    <div class="header">
      <h2 v-if="founderChairman === true">Member List One</h2>
      <h2 v-else>Member List Two</h2>
      <img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <carousel :minSwipeDistance="384" :perPage="1" :paginationEnabled="false" :navigationEnabled="true" navigationNextLabel="<i>NEXT</i>"
  navigationPrevLabel="<i>BACK</i>" :navigateTo="selectedListIndex" @pagechange="OnPageChange">
      <slide v-for="(member, index) in selectedList" :key="index">
        <div class="member-bio-page" :member="member" v-on:showContent="showContent">
          <div class="bio">
            <div class="portrait-image">
                <img :src="member.imgSrc" />
            </div>
            <div class="bio-container">
              <div class="inner-scroll" v-bind:style="{top: scrollVar + 'px'}">
                <div class="english"></div>
                <div class="pin-name">
                  <img :src="member.pin" />
                  <h1>{{ member.name }}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="description-container">
                  <div class="para">
                    <p class="quote" v-html="member.quote"></p>
                    <p v-html="member.bio"></p>
                    <div class="spanish"></div>
                    <p class="quote" v-html="member.spanishQuote"></p>
                    <p v-html="member.spanishBio"></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-buttons">
              <div>
                <!-- set the class of active is the scroll variable is less than 0-->
                <img class="btn-scroll" v-bind:class="{ 'active': scrollVar < 0 }" @click="scrollUp" src="@/assets/arrow-up.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <!-- set the class of active is the scroll variable is greater than the height of the scrollable inner container-->
                <img class="btn-scroll" v-bind:class="{ 'active': scrollVar > pageChangeHeight }" @click="scrollDown" src="@/assets/arrow-down.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="eng-span">
              <a href="javascript:" class="english" @click="toEnglish">English</a>
              <a href="javascript:" class="spanish" @click="toSpanish">Español</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="play-button">
            <!-- if the array members has a property of video, then the play button will show on the slide. If not it will not show the image -->
            <img v-if="member.hasOwnProperty('video')" @click="showContent" src="@/assets/play-button.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <MemberBioPage :member="member" v-on:showContent="showContent"/> -->
      </slide>
    </carousel>
    <modal name="video-modal"
           :width="1706"
           :height="960">
      <video width="1706" height="960" :src="(selectedList && selectedList[this.currentPage]) ? selectedList[this.currentPage].video : ''" autoplay />
    </modal>
    <div class="footer-controls">

      <div class="footer-bar">
          <p>Tap Back or Next to view additional profiles.</p>
          <p>Tap the arrows to scroll text up or down.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-container">
        <img class="nav-bubble" src="@/assets/navigation-bubble-bio-page.png" alt="An image where the back, next and close button sit" />
      </div>

      <button class="close-button" @click="closeInfo">
        <img src="@/assets/x-close-button.png" />
        CLOSE
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentPage: 0,
      pageChangeHeight: -10,
      scrollVar: 0
    }
  },
  components: {
    // MemberBioPage,
    Carousel,
    Slide
  },
  mounted () {
    this.enableArrows()
  },
  updated () {
    this.enableArrows()
  },
  computed: {
    selectedList () {
      return this.$store.state.selectedList
    },
    selectedListIndex () {
      return this.$store.state.selectedListIndex
    },
    founderChairman () {
      return this.$store.state.founderChairman
    }
  },
  methods: {
    enableArrows () {
      var outerHeight
      var innerHeight
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide-active').length > 0) {
        outerHeight = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide-active .bio-container')[0].clientHeight
        innerHeight = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide-active .inner-scroll')[0].clientHeight
      } else {
        outerHeight = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide .bio-container')[0].clientHeight
        innerHeight = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide .inner-scroll')[0].clientHeight
      }
      this.pageChangeHeight = outerHeight - innerHeight
      return this.pageChangeHeight
    },
    scrollUp () {
      this.scrollVar += 40
      console.log(this.scrollVar += 40)
    },
    scrollDown () {
      this.scrollVar -= 40
      console.log(this.scrollVar)
    },
    OnPageChange (newPageIndex) {
      this.scrollVar = 0
      this.currentPage = newPageIndex
      this.pageChangeHeight = -10
    },
    closeInfo () {
      if (this.$store.state.selectedList === this.$store.state.foundersList) {
        this.$store.commit('setSelectedState', this.$store.state.foundersList)
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Carousel' })
      } else if (this.$store.state.selectedList === this.$store.state.chairmanList) {
        this.$store.commit('setSelectedState', this.$store.state.chairmanList)
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Carousel' })
      }
    },
    showContent () {
      this.$modal.show('video-modal')
    },
    toEnglish () {
      this.scrollVar = 0
    },
    toSpanish () {
      var spanishPos
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide-active').length > 0) {
        spanishPos = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide-active .spanish')[0].offsetTop
      } else {
        spanishPos = document.querySelectorAll('.VueCarousel-slide .spanish')[0].offsetTop
      }
      this.scrollVar = -spanishPos
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my store index file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import chairmans from '@/data/chairmans-club'
import founders from '@/data/founders-circle'
import memoriam from '@/data/in-memoriam'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    finishedLoading: false,
    transitioning: false,
    foundersList: founders,
    chairmanList: chairmans,
    selectedList: founders,
    selectedListIndex: -1,
    founderChairman: true,
    inMemoriam: memoriam,
    idleTimer: {
      id: null,
      duration: 1
    },
    idleTimeoutModal: {
      show: false,
      duration: 1
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setSelectedState (state, list) {
      state.selectedList = list
    },
    setSelectedListIndex (state, idx) {
      state.selectedListIndex = idx
    },
    showIdleTimeoutModal (state, value) {
      state.idleTimeoutModal.show = value
    },
    founderChairmanClicked (state, data) {
      state.founderChairman = data
    },
    setInMemoriam (state, content) {
      state.inMemoriam = content
    }
  },
  actions: {
    restartIdleTimer ({ state, commit }) {
      clearTimeout(state.idleTimer.id)

      state.idleTimer.id = setTimeout(() => {
        commit('showIdleTimeoutModal', true)
      }, state.idleTimer.duration * 1000)
    },
    stopIdleTimer ({ state }) {
      clearTimeout(state.idleTimer.id)
    }
  }
})

export default store
```

and an example of the data i am pulling:

```
const event = [
  {
    index: 0,
    name: 'Member Name',
    carouselImage: require('@/assets/carousel-images/image.jpg'),
    drawerImage: require('@/assets/drawer-images/drawerimage.jpg'),
    imgSrc: require('@/assets/bio-images/bioimage.jpg'),
    quote: '“quote.”',
    spanishQuote: `“spanish quote.”`,
    bio: '<p>bio copy here</p>',
    spanishBio: '<p>spanish bio copy</p>',
    pin: require('@/assets/pin.png')
  }
]

export default event
```

Comment: Your current snippet is not helpful in understanding or reproducing the problem. Since it seems to be related mostly to UI state, I suggest simplifying it by removing references to store with internal component state/data and removing any methods/data/computed irrelevant to the question being asked. You could also reduce the slider to 2-3 slides and provide all  necessary data in component's `data`. It  would probably be a good idea to create a [mcve] on codesandbox.io. Simplify it as much as possible while making sure it still features the problem.

Comment: The biggest problem the snippet currently has is it lacks essential parts for reproducing the error: a) CSS rules applying to your elements. b) a sample of the rendered data. Even if someone wanted to create a runnable snippet for you, they couldn't, as they don't have all required elements. This makes your question unanswerable and, therefore, off-topic here. Please add sufficient detail to make it answerable and (ideally) more generic (as in, useful for future visitors with a similar problem). Doing so would radically increase its chances of getting useful answers.

Comment: okay, i will try and put something together. really appreciate the responses!

Comment: to add to this, i didn't add the styling as I had removed it and the issue still persisted. Let me gather code from my store file and add it here for now, but I am also making a simplified version to share